# Multiple charts in a SQL Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm preparing a report in SQL Reporting Services 2012 and I want to show a variable number of charts based on the data I have.

So, the (simplified) data source looks like

```
ID Name    Group       Sales
=============================
1  apples   fruit        15
2  bananas  fruit        25
3  carrots  vegetable    10
4  brocolli vegetable    19
5  tuna     fish         15
```

For each group - show a graph based on the names and values:

- chart 1 - fruit sales
- chart 2 - vegetable sales
- chart 3 - fish sales
- and so on...

But I do not want to hard-code the group names - if a new group is added to the db, a new chart should pop-up in the report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a table based on your dataset grouping on "Group" and then embed the chart in the table, SSRS should take care of the rest.

Comment: That is the general principle. It takes a bit of fiddling around with the Report Builder to get it to work...

Comment: In my experience that pretty much sums up Report Builder - I've never been able to get away with it!